# Is there a way to control/use Google Play Protect together with microG (open source Google Play service alternative)?

Tags: security, google-play-services, micro-g, play-protect

I'm facing a tricky scenario, sometime back I decided to discontinue using Google Play Services in favour of an [open source alternative](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2184/29904) - [microG](https://microg.org) due to constant problems and crashing of several Google applications on my device.

As Google launched [Google Play Protect](https://www.android.com/play-protect/)<sup>1</sup> feature (on all Android devices running Google Play Services 11 or later), this seems to be missing or at least I'm not sure how to use it (i.e enable or disable it) with microG.

With a device running Google Play Services, one can easily control it by navigating to: `Settings ➡ Google ➡ Security ➡ Google Play Protect`

I wish to be able to control this feature on microG so I can control/disable constant false positive notifications about my installed applications being harmful, and also to have my applications regularly scanned.

Is there way to control "Play Protect" on a device running microG, or at least to integrate via another means, perhaps an Xposed module?

---

<sup>1</sup>

> Google Play Protect is a feature that is, essentially, an evolution of
>   the company’s “Verify Apps” service that was rolled out to Android
>   many years ago. The feature, which will be enabled by default on all
>   Android devices, is meant to be a real-time malware scanner that will
>   scan every installed or about-to-be installed app and inform users in
>   case there’s something amiss.

Comment: Not yet built into microG, maybe?  Also, there isn't much control available with Play Protect, at least not on my Pixel...its pretty much an on or off thing.

Comment: Thanks for your response @SiXandSeven8ths, I wanted to **turn it on/off** at will with microG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Play Protect can be disabled by editing these XML files:

> /data/system/users/0/settings_secure.xml

```
package_verifier_user_consent=-1
```

> /data/system/users/0/settings_global.xml

```
package_verifier_enable=0
upload_apk_enable=0
```

**Edit**

On older Android, it is stored in a database located at: `/data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db`. You need to use some database editor to change that parameter

Comment: Thanks but the target device is running android 4.3, and that path does not exist on this android version, but +1 nevertheless for looking into this!

Comment: On older Android, it is stored in a database located at: /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db. You need to use some database editor to change that parameter.

Comment: @TimJosten Please [edit] your answer to include that information. Comments are temporary and not searchable, so your useful addition is at risk of being lost!

Comment: @TimJosten, I have intergrated your last comment into your answer for the same reason suggested by DanHulme