# Issues with gmail not recognising Google Play services

Tags: gmail, huawei, google-play-services

I have a tablet that came with **no** Google (suite) applications however I  managed to install them manually and are working pretty fine. The only issue is with **Gmail** application which seems to have problem with Google play services.

Everytime I open the Gmail application it shows a rather awkward, uncommon error meassage that reads: **`Gmail relies on Google Play services, which is not supported by your device`**. Contact the manufacturer for assistance` and **I can't sync new emails or send new mails.**

[image]

In my opinion this is a false alert, since other Google applications, work well and seem to interact well with the Google play services.

Previously to solve this issue with reference to Gmail, I have ditched Google play services in support of [microG](https://microg.org) which works well with Gmail (version 6.4120760496) (as in I can sync new inbox messages and send mails from within the app).

However microG still [misses some important aspects](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/187097/209414) which is why I tried to switch to using default Google Play services implementation.

Things I have tried to resolve the issue:

- clearing cache/data for Gmail, Google Play services, Google service framework
- factory rest
- ROM flashing (initally works but after some period of use the error shows up again)
- Updating to latest Google Play services
- Wiping cache
- Unistalling and reinstalling Gmail (initially works but error starts showing after some time)

Any way to fix this?

Comment: This isn't really deserving of an answer but why not try EasyMail or some other client.  I don't particular care for the default Gmail interface anyways.

Comment: Thanks William, I also have been considering alternatives even Outlook mail if doesn't give me problems

Answer (score 1):

I believe it might not be a false alert... Your tablet may not be certified for Google Play, and that's probably why you are seeing this message.

Try this:

> On your computer browser, go to the Google Play Services app page on the Play Store: https://play.google.com/store/apps/d...roid.gms&hl=en. Click the Installed button, and see if you can select your RCA tablet to install to.

Got it from [here](https://forums.androidcentral.com/ask-question/504035-why-google-play-services-missing-my-android-tablet-after-factory-reset.html)

Comment: But then other apps work fine,also I have already installed google play services on my device and only gmail is problematic